# Trailing slash in Flask route

Tags: python, flask

Take for example the following two routes.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/somewhere")
def no_trailing_slash():
    #case one

@app.route("/someplace/")
def with_trailing_slash():
    #case two
```

According to [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#variable-rules) the following is understood:

- In case one, a request for the route `"/somewhere/"` will return a 404 response. `"/somewhere"` is valid.
- In case two, `"/someplace/"` is valid and `"/someplace"` will redirect to `"/someplace/"`

The behavior I would like to see is the *'inverse'* of the **case two** behavior. e.g. `"/someplace/"` will redirect to `"/someplace"` rather than the other way around. Is there a way to define a route to take on this behavior?

From my understanding, `strict_slashes=False` can be set on the route to get effectively the same behavior of case two in case one, but what I'd like to do is get the redirect behavior to always redirect to the URL *without* the trailing slash.

One solution I've thought of using would be using an error handler for 404's, something like this. (Not sure if this would even work)

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    if request.path.endswith("/") and request.path[:-1] in all_endpoints:
        return redirect(request.path[:-1]), 302
    return render_template("404.html"), 404
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better solution, like a drop-in app configuration of some sort, similar to `strict_slashes=False` that I can apply globally. Maybe a blueprint or url rule?

Comment: implement both seperately and have `/somplace/` redirect to `/someplace`?

Comment: What I have noticed is when you have `DEBUG=True` in your Flask config the trailing spaces are not redirected but when `DEBUG=False` then it is redirected.

Comment: @Busturdust that could probably work, but would be kind of a pain to manage. Some other ideas I've had involve using an [error handler](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers) that returns a redirect if the slashless endpoint exists. It may also be possible to use a blueprint of some sort. But I already use a 404 error handler for something else (it could be baked in, but I'd rather not) and I'm not sure if it can be achieved with a blueprint. The ideal solution would be a drop-in like a global url rule.

Comment: @kiran.koduru That's an interesting observation. I'll have to take a look at that, although I don't think I'll be using the debug flag in production, for obvious reasons. I typically deploy Flask using Tornado or gEvent. Even when I set `app.debug = True` it doesn't appear to take in the gevent WSGI environment. I'm sure there's a way to solve *that* problem, but is another question and as explained, probably not an applicable solution to *this* question, for a production environment.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You are on the right tracking with using `strict_slashes`, which you can configure on the Flask app itself. This will set the `strict_slashes` flag to `False` for every route that is created

```
app = Flask('my_app')
app.url_map.strict_slashes = False
```

Then you can use `before_request` to detect the trailing `/` for a redirect. Using `before_request` will allow you to  not require special logic to be applied to each route individually

```
@app.before_request
def clear_trailing():
    from flask import redirect, request

    rp = request.path 
    if rp != '/' and rp.endswith('/'):
        return redirect(rp[:-1])
```

Comment: Sure, I've got this much figured out. However, this will redirect to the URL *with* the trailing slash. Requests for the non-trailing slash will be a 302 redirect. I want the trailing slashes to redirect to the non-trailing slash URL.

Comment: That looks interesting. This could probably work for the solution. If I took this approach, I would probably first check to see if the slash*less* route exists before redirecting there, to avoid redirecting to a URL that ultimately will be a 404 anyhow. But yes, this looks good. I'm not sure how I feel about registering a function to run *every time for every route*. I'm weighing this against using a 404 error handler that will check if the slashless route exists, which I think only runs if a 404 occurs and may or may not have a performance implications compared to this.

Answer (score 9):

If you want both routes to be handled the same way, I would do this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/someplace/")
@app.route("/someplace")
def slash_agnostic():
    #code for both routes
```

Comment: What if `/someplace` is the namespace prefix?

Comment: @ZobayerHasan, I don't understand the question. Are you describing a path like this: `/someplace/someplace`?

Comment: no, I was using flask restplus. In restplus, namespaces are used just like blueprints. For example, I could register a namespace with `/someplace` prefix, then in my resource class, I could just set `@api.route('/')` to create the path `/someplace/`

Comment: I have not used restplus so I'm not sure if something similar would work there.

Comment: That's fine, since I later discovered after doing some more reading on REST api route design, a trailing slash actually stands for something. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187006/201023

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the option strict_slashes=False in your route definition:

```
app.Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/someplace", strict_slashes=False)
# Your code goes here
```