# Flask route and slashes

Tags: python, flask

In flask route there is an issue for me

My route is

```
@app.route('/user/<string:user>/')
def user(user):
    return '' + str(user)
```

when I visit localhost:5000/user/ahmed/ with slash at end of url, every thing is ok

but if I visit localhost:5000/user/ahmed without last slash

flask redirect me to localhost:5000/user/ahmed/None and give me 404

Comment: remove the slash after <string:user>

Comment: `@app.route('/user/<string:user>')`

Comment: if i removed it , route will not work for both cases

Comment: i cant edit it , because my problem still un-solved

Comment: A solution to this was proposed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365390/trailing-slash-in-flask-route

Answer (score 4):

Here is some relevant information taken directly from the [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/quickstart/#routing)

> ## Unique URLs / Redirection Behavior
>
> Flask’s URL rules are based on Werkzeug’s routing module. The idea
> behind that module is to ensure beautiful and unique URLs based on
> precedents laid down by Apache and earlier HTTP servers.
>
> Take these two rules:
>
> ```
> @app.route('/projects/')
> def projects():
>     return 'The project page'
>
> @app.route('/about')
> def about():
>     return 'The about page'
> ```
>
> Though they look rather similar, they differ in their use of the trailing
> slash in the URL definition. In
> the first case, the canonical URL for the projects endpoint has a
> trailing slash. In that sense, it is similar to a folder on a
> filesystem. Accessing it without a trailing slash will cause Flask to
> redirect to the canonical URL with the trailing slash.
>
> In the second case, however, the URL is defined without a trailing
> slash, rather like the pathname of a file on UNIX-like systems.
> Accessing the URL with a trailing slash will produce a 404 “Not Found”
> error.
>
> This behavior allows relative URLs to continue working even if the
> trailing slash is omitted, consistent with how Apache and other
> servers work. Also, the URLs will stay unique, which helps search
> engines avoid indexing the same page twice.

Comment: and then what is the solution for my problem ?