# Why does putting the word "Admin" in the route of a flask application cause the page to 404?

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

I'm creating a new route in our flask application.  When I go to add an 'n' to the end of 'tableAdmi', it causes the new route to 404.  What in the world could be causing this?

I have the following routes

```
@application.route('/console/tableAdmi')
def tableAdmin2wtf():
    return flask.render_template('formTest.html')

@application.route('/console/tableAdmin')
def editTable():
    return flask.render_template('formTest.html')
```

Other routes exist with the word Admin included like '/console/bulkAdministration' and render without a 404.

[image: Same html, one 404's]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, you should include as formatted text in the question. Also, you should include the front-end code to close the loop of any doubts about why `Admin` might be special (I'm already thinking either a clash with `flask-admin` - unlikely - or that you haven't updated your templates)

Comment: I added the code.  Both routes are rending the same template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the n letter that's causing the error, but the `/` at the end of the URL.

`example.com/tableAdmin` and `example.com/tableAdmin/` are different URLs in this context. You need to handle them separately or add to the same handler.

You can do this:

```py
@application.route('/console/tableAdmin')
@application.route('/console/tableAdmin/')
def editTable():
    return flask.render_template('formTest.html')
```

and the URL will become slash-agnostic. If you want to make all your URL slash-agnostic, you need to handle and remove the slashes in `@app.before_request`.
See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365390/trailing-slash-in-flask-route/40365514) for more details.