# Which form of routing is better in flask, @app.route("/login') or @app.route("/login/")?

Tags: python, flask

`@app.route("/login")`

OR

`@app.route("/login/")`

Which routing is better in flask or in general?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trailing slash in Flask route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365390/trailing-slash-in-flask-route)

Comment: yup thanks, I couldn't get the term 'trailing slash' at the time of writing hence had to submit a new question explainingg the whole scenario. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

[Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior) suggest that trailing slash will cause /login to be redirected to /login/ .

Either works but usually "/login" by itself is preferred. You seem to be creating a login page, so since it is a page and not a list of resources there shouldn't be a trailing slash.