# Flask URL works like this "/api/hello" but not like this "/api/hello/"

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Flask URL interpreter recognizes `/api/hello` but not when passed like this `/api/hello/`

Is there to have it work both ways?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365390/trailing-slash-in-flask-route?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this
@app.route("/api/hello/")
In this way both url will work

Answer (score 0):

Add a `/` after `hello` so it will redirect to `/api/hello/` even if request is done on `/api/hello`

`@app.route('/app/hello/')`