Uploaded files are lost after automatic redirect to trailing '/'
From the flask documentation a link when used without trailing slash redirects to it with the slash.
In my case with the url ending in /uploads/, the following code prints my files when I upload them from localhost:5000/uploads/ but files is empty when I upload them from localhost:5000/uploads.How can I keep the trailing slash in the following route but still be able to get uploaded files even after the redirection?
@app.route('/uploads/')
def upload_file():
    files = request.files.getlist('files')
    print(files)


Do you mean this? All 3 solutions work

Yes they work. But I want to know if it is possible to get the files out of the box after Flask redirects /uploads to /uploads/.

I don't really get what you mean by 'get the files out of the box', you are not redirecting anything but handling both uploads and uploads/ in the same function. If it's about the files you uploaded then your code should handle them not the route address. If possible can you add what result you expect/want exactly?

Please read https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/quickstart/#unique-urls-redirection-behavior

I'm guessing it's just a typo for the question here, If not, you've used upload in the route and uploads in the urls.

The redirect isn't actually done entirely by Flask. Flask only returns a 301 or 302 redirect (probably 302), and whatever http client you are using will need to decide what to do with that.
See this for a discussion of what would happen:
HTTP: POST request receives a 302, should the redirect-request be a GET?
This is the relevant bit, a comment from Chrome sources :
  // For 303 redirects, all request methods except HEAD are converted to GET,
  // as per the latest httpbis draft.  The draft also allows POST requests to
  // be converted to GETs when following 301/302 redirects, for historical
  // reasons. Most major browsers do this and so shall we.  Both RFC 2616 and
  // the httpbis draft say to prompt the user to confirm the generation of new
  // requests, other than GET and HEAD requests, but IE omits these prompts and
  // so shall we.

File uploads would generally be a POST request. In any case, it isn't going to be GET. So you normally can't rely on your client resending the file in a fresh POST request. Unless you're writing the client as well and make sure to handle this case (which I do not recommend), that is.
Ideally, the non-slash URL would be semantically correct one to use. I presume you want to retain the one with the slash for backward compatibility reasons.
The options suggested by @AdityaDN in his comments are what you should be looking for if you do need both to work. Specifically, you need to prevent the redirect from ever happening, and have both endpoints have functions which act immediately on the request. Personally, I'm partial to the second answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54118051/1934174), assuming it works. I haven't tried it myself.
